# Find top and bottom two rows and read column value into a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

**This is my sample data frame.**

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Matt', 'John', 'Sam', 'Harry', 'Don', 'Julia', 'Chris', 'Nelson'],
           'Age': [30, 34, 56, 43, 67, 23, 19, 8],
           'Marks': [100, 200, 434, 543, 234, 412,678, 832],
           'Weight': [89, 56, 74, 34, 98, 102, 71, 80]})
```

I need to find out the two highest and two lowest values per columns and return Name and corresponding values for those rows. I can get them individually but is there a way to get them all together in a table in one code

**This is the sample output I am looking for (one table each for lowest and highest values). The table below is for highest values.**

| Column Name | Name | Rank | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | Don | 1 | 67 |
| Age | Sam | 2 | 56 |
| Marks | Nelson | 1 | 832 |
| Marks | Chris | 2 | 678 |

There are more than 80 columns. I am new to Python and some sort of loop would be really helpful.

Comment: If a loop would be helpful, why don't you write one?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Python. still learning around python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nlargest` and `nsmallest` to get the values and make a data frame by `concat`.

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Matt', 'John', 'Sam', 'Harry', 'Don', 'Julia', 'Chris', 'Nelson'],
           'Age': [30, 34, 56, 43, 67, 23, 19, 8],
           'Marks': [100, 200, 434, 543, 234, 412,678, 832],
           'Weight': [89, 56, 74, 34, 98, 102, 71, 80]})
queries = []
for c in ['Age', 'Marks', 'Weight']:
  query = df.nlargest(2, [c])[['Name', c]].rename(columns={c: 'Value'}).reset_index(drop=True)
  query['Column Name'] = c
  query['Rank'] = query.index + 1
  query = query[['Column Name', 'Name', 'Rank', 'Value']]
  queries.append(query)
new_df = pd.concat(queries).reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. Only the highest values are handled to illustrate the concept. It is an alternate way that uses the append method:

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Matt', 'John', 'Sam', 'Harry', 'Don', 'Julia', 'Chris', 'Nelson'],
           'Age': [30, 34, 56, 43, 67, 23, 19, 8],
           'Marks': [100, 200, 434, 543, 234, 412,678, 832],
           'Weight': [89, 56, 74, 34, 98, 102, 71, 80]})

df_new =pd.DataFrame({'Column Name':[], 'Name':[], 'Rank':[], 'Value':[]})

for (columnName, columnData) in df.iteritems():
    if columnName == "Name":
        continue
    df2 = df.sort_values(by=[columnName], ascending=False).head(2).reset_index()
    for (columnName2, columnData2) in df2.iteritems():
        names = df2['Name']
        if columnName2 == columnName:
            for i in range(len(list(columnData2))):
                df_temp = {'Column Name':columnName, 'Name':names[i], 'Rank':i+1, 'Value':columnData2[i]}
                df_new = df_new.append(df_temp, ignore_index=True)


print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
  Column Name    Name  Rank  Value
0         Age     Don   1.0   67.0
1         Age     Sam   2.0   56.0
2       Marks  Nelson   1.0  832.0
3       Marks   Chris   2.0  678.0
4      Weight   Julia   1.0  102.0
5      Weight     Don   2.0   98.0
```